# My Mariadb fails and shuts down after running with a timeout

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux

My Mariadb version is

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

My machine is a ubuntu server:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mypc 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run it, I get

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql

Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have no clue what the logs mean. It runs for a few seconds and then tries shutting down the database server with a timeout. During the timeout, I can even connect to the database via

```
mysql -u root
```

no problem, but I know something is failing and shutting down the db server.

I follow the instructions:

when running

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
```

, I get

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.23 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2020-08-07 08:16:58 UTC; 8min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 19512 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 19516 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 19526 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 19577 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 19577 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200807  8:16:57
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1701105; transaction id 167
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.23 database server.
```

and when running

```
journalctl -xe
```

, it gives me this:

```
Aug 07 08:16:34 mypc sudo[19509]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc sudo[19509]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc sudo[19509]:       me : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/apache2/sites-available ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start mysql
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc sudo[19509]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.23 database server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 5094.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.23-MariaDB-1:10.3.23+maria~bionic) starting as process 19577 ...
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16364 (request: 32183)
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.23 started; log sequence number 1701096; transaction id 166
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #1 encryption thread id 139817862018816 total threads 4.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #2 encryption thread id 139817853626112 total threads 4.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #3 encryption thread id 139817845233408 total threads 4.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating #4 encryption thread id 139817560045312 total threads 4.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] Using encryption key id 1 for temporary files
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200807  8:16:37
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:37 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc mysqld[19577]: Version: '10.3.23-MariaDB-1:10.3.23+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:37 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788197.855:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc systemd[1]: mariadb.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.615:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200807  8:16:57
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.643:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.743:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.843:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.943:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:57 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788217.947:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1701105; transaction id 167
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc mysqld[19577]: 2020-08-07  8:16:58 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc audit[19577]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788218.683:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1596788218.683:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=19577 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=129 ouid=0
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'.
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.23 database server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 5094 and the job result is failed.
Aug 07 08:16:58 mypc sudo[19509]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 07 08:17:01 mypc CRON[19633]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 07 08:17:01 mypc CRON[19634]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 07 08:17:01 mypc CRON[19633]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 07 08:17:06 mypc kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:80:20:da:7f:64:43:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

---

Configs:

> /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

```
...

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
early-plugin-load="keyring_file.so"
```

and

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

[mysqld]
#early-plugin-load="keyring_file.so"
# at-rest encryption
plugin_load_add              = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/rest/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey  = FILE:/etc/mysql/rest/keyfile.passwd
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CBC
 
innodb_encrypt_tables            = ON
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables  = ON
innodb_encrypt_log               = ON
innodb_encryption_threads        = 4
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
encrypt-tmp-disk-tables          = 1
encrypt-tmp-files                = 1
encrypt-binlog                   = 1
aria_encrypt_tables              = ON
```

I removed all encryption related config lines and ran

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

It did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're having issues with apparmor, still loading the MySQL apparmor profile.

According to [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-community-mariadb-troubles-only-running-after-reboot-times-out-when-try/), MariaDB's recommendation is to disable the mysqld profile like so:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
$ sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld 

# Verify
$ sudo aa-status
```

It seems that [MariaDB recommends](https://salsa.debian.org/mariadb-team/mariadb-10.1/blob/stretch/debian/apparmor-profile) not running MariaDB with an apparmor profile:

```
# This file is intensionally [sic] empty to disable apparmor by default for newer
# versions of MariaDB, while providing seamless upgrade from older versions
# and from mysql, where apparmor is used.
#
# By default, we do not want to have any apparmor profile for the MariaDB
# server. It does not provide much useful functionality/security, and causes
# several problems for users who often are not even aware that apparmor
# exists and runs on their system.
#
# Users can modify and maintain their own profile, and in this case it will
# be used.
#
# When upgrading from previous version, users who modified the profile
# will be promptet to keep or discard it, while for default installs
# we will automatically disable the profile.
```

Comment: Good answer (Welcome back), Derek !!! +1